Codeigniter 4 - Helper does not loading
Error
Call to undefined function Encrypt()
I'm having some problems with my helpers! On localhost they loaded without problems but now that I deployed them on my home server they don't load... I already loaded autoload/BaseController and nothing, the error is persistent.
This is my helpers:

Email_Helper.php
Encryption_Helper.php
Functions_Helper.php
Logger_Helpper.php

My Base Controller:
protected $helpers = ['form', 'encryption', 'functions', 'logger', 'email'];

Autoload:
    public $helpers = [
        'Encryption_Helper',
        'Email_Helper',
        'Functions_Helper',
        'Logger_Helper'
    ];

And also, I tried to:
helper(['form', 'encryption', 'functions']);

I can't get out of my problem, can anyone help?
I'm having some problems with my helpers! On localhost they loaded without problems but now that I deployed them on my home server they don't load... I already loaded autoload/BaseController and nothing, the error is persistent.

Its most likely your app/Config/Paths.php file - have a look there and see if tha thelps

Did you try to change the name of your class name and file name of your helper to lowercase?

Like @Roshan said the filenames need to be lowercase.
